# How does Liferay compare to Weblogic and other portal servers?

Tags: liferay

I need to select between Liferay, Weblogic and other portal servers on the market?  Has anyone done a performance test amongst them?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure where did you get that liferay is the best of breed. I have actually used on many sites and I am trying to getting rid of it. The documention is really bad and out of date and the portlet out of the box are ridiculous. 
Blogs and wikis portlet are not up to any nice web2.0 site and the framework is rather clumsy than nice to work with. 
The config mode for portlet has to be developed using liferay framework...good luck.
It is easy to start but a nightmare to extend and to use. Be aware if you are looking for an enterprise portal.

Comment: I 2nd that the documentation is nearly 'non-existant' for Liferay 5.2.  We are trying to run with Liferay and my company just forked out money for training, so that might help.

Answer (score 0):

I have used several and you will find that Liferay is the best of breed. It is usually first to implement new industry standards, is the most secure and is even certified to run on thousands of CPUs concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

Gartner reported at one time that WebLogic Portal was 2 years ahead of everyone else technology-wise. It is being used by companies like Verizon, Wells Fargo, Level 3, CitiGroup, etc. who spend quite a bit of money doing their homework about which technologies they invest in. My expertise is primarily in WebLogic portal (full disclosure: I worked for BEA Systems in their portal group) but since leaving I have worked with LifeRay and WebSphere. Frankly, they are just not even close to the kind of maturity, technical feature set, and ease of development you'll find in WebLogic Portal.